# Update some html when ruby on rails is live

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, edit

I have a Ruby on Rails website online. I tried changing the HTML, but saw no change when I uploaded the file via FTP.

I've even checked by making a simple change such as adding an HTML heading:

```
<h1>omais</h1>
```

I checked the online page which I edited and looked at the source code in the browser, and confirmed that I was on the correct page.

Is there some kind of command to inform the project that there are changes that has been made in the HTML file?

I am new to Rails but good in PHP.

Any help, Thanks

Comment: Try after restarting server and cleaning browser cache

Comment: Thanks, i just restart my server and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826309/update-some-html-when-ruby-on-rails-is-live?noredirect=1#comment40403433_25826309), I am adding answer here also, so that other programmers can get help from your question.

---

You need to restart your rails server or just try to start app server, which will leads to rails server restart. If still you face the issue, try to clear your browser's cache.